Can alpha-wrap be run in parallel?
I am looking into using alpha-wrapping for generating surface mesh of some CAD models. Can alpha-wrap be used in parallel ?
I am a beginner when it comes to CGAL. I have used alpha-wrap to generate some surface meshes using CGAL CAD examples. Would like to know if there is already an existing capability to use alpha-wrap in parallel.

Are you asking because you noticed it was too slow on one very big model? Or too slow when processing many small models? Or some other reason?

I am looking to develop a wrapper but the requirement is should be parallelizable. I was looking through the literature and came across alpha wrapper.

As of CGAL 6.0, there is no parallel mode for the "3D Alpha Wrapping" component.
However, you could process your objects in parallel with a program taking one input, and running multiple instances of your program.
